# Update collection to change the rank

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb

i have a mongodb collection that I sort by the amount of points each item has, and it shows a rank according to it's place in the collection :

```
db.collection('websites').find({}).sort({  "points": -1 }).forEach(doc => {
    
  rank++;
  doc.rank = rank;
  delete doc._id;
  console.log(doc)
```

[image]

Si I thought to myself : **Ok, I'm gonna update the rank in the collection**, so I added this :

```
 db.collection('websites').updateMany({},
    { $set: { rank: doc.rank } }
)
```

But I was too good to be true, and it updates every single item with the same rank, which changes at each refresh, what exactly is going on, here ?

[image]
[image]

**EDIT : I managed to do it by doing this :**

```
rank = 0;

db.collection('websites').find({}).sort({  "points": -1 }).forEach(doc => {

  rank++;
  doc.rank = rank;
  //delete doc._id;
  console.log(doc._id);

  db.collection('websites').updateMany({_id : doc._id},
    { $set: { rank: doc.rank } },
    { upsert: true }
)

})
```

Comment: Exactly what was your intent in the update?   Which docs were to be updated and how?

Comment: Every single ones, with their according rank in the collection sorted by the amount of points, if for example url.com has 37 000 points and url.org has 25 000 points, then url.com is rank 1 and url.org is rank 2 , you got it ?

Comment: Oh -- so you want to sort all the docs by points, then "rerank" them from 1 to n in that order?

Comment: Yes, that's right ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it by doing:

```
rank = 0;

db.collection('websites').find({}).sort({  "points": -1 }).forEach(doc => {
  rank++;
  doc.rank = rank;
  //delete doc._id;
  console.log(doc._id);

  db.collection('websites').updateMany({_id : doc._id},
    { $set: { rank: doc.rank } },
    { upsert: true }
  )
})
```

**Thank you everyone !**

Comment: Easiest yes but not the most exciting.  :-)   Probably best to use `updateOne` not `updateMany` since you are updating on `_id` and there can be only 1.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
db.collection('websites')
    .updateOne( //update only one
    {rank: doc.rank}, //update the one where rank is the sent in parameter doc.rank
    { $set: { rank: doc.rank } } // if multiple docs have the same rank you should send in more parameters
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection('websites').updateMany({/*All docs match*/},
    { $set: { rank: doc.rank } }
)
```

Reason it updates same rank because you have no filter which means it matches all docs in the collection and you have `updateMany`

You need to set a filter to restrict docs to be updated.

```
db.collection('websites').updateMany({id: "someID"},
        { $set: { rank: doc.rank } }
    )
```

Comment: The thing is : I'm trying to update every single line and add their rank respectivelly  
like if doc.rank for a line is 1, then it updates it's "rank" to 1, if 27 , then 27 etc ...

Comment: What is line here?

Comment: Every items in the database, those are url with an amount of points, a url, an ID of the user who posted it, and then.. I want to add a rank according to it's place in the database sorted by the amount of points

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that mongo is using the same **doc.rank** value to update all the records that match the filter criteria (all records in your case). Now you have two options to resolve the issue -

1. **Works but is less efficient)** - Idea here is that you need to calculate the rank for each website that you want to update. loop throuh all the document and run below query which will update every document with it's calculated rank. You could probably think that this is inefficient and you would be right. We are making large number of network calls to update the records. Worse part is that the slowness is unbounded and will get slower as number of records increases.

```js
db.collection('websites')
  .updateOne( 
    { id: 'docIdThatNeedsToBeUpdated'}, 
    { $set: { rank: 'calculatedRankOfTheWebsite' } } 
  )
```

2. **Efficient option** - Use the same technique to calculate the rank for each website and loop through it to generate the update statement as above. But this time you would not make the update calls separately for all the websites. Rather you would use **Bulk update** technique. You add all your update statement to a batch and execute them all at one go.

```js
//loop and use below two line to add the statements to a batch.
var bulk = db.websites.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
bulk.find({ id: 'docIdThatNeedsToBeUpdated' })
  .updateOne({
    $set: {
      rank: 'calculatedRankOfTheWebsite'
    }
  });

//execute all of the statement at one go outside of the loop
bulk.execute();
```

Comment: The thing is : I'm trying to update every single line and add their rank respectivelly like if doc.rank for a line is 1, then it updates it's "rank" to 1, if 27 , then 27 etc ...

It's not a specific ID, it's all of them but with their according rank

Answer (score 0):

The OP states we want to sort all the docs by points, then "rerank" them from 1 to n in that order and update the DB.  Here is an example of where "aggregate is the new update" thanks to the power of `$merge` onto the *same* collection as the input:

```js
db.foo.aggregate([
    // Get everything in descending order...                                                     
    {$sort: {'points':-1}}

    // ... and turn it into a big array:                                              
    ,{$group: {_id:null, X:{$push: '$$ROOT'}}}

    // Walk the array and incrementally set rank.  The input arg
    // is $X and we set $X so we are overwriting the old X:                                    
    ,{$addFields: {X: {$function: {
        body: function(items) {
            for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                items[i]['rank'] = (i+1);
            }
            return items;
        },
        args: [ '$X' ],
        lang: "js"
        }}
    }}

    // Get us back to regular docs, not an array:                                     
    ,{$unwind: '$X'}
    ,{$replaceRoot: {newRoot: '$X'}}

    // ... and update everything:                                                     
    ,{$merge: {
        into: "foo",
        on: [ "_id" ],
        whenMatched: "merge",
        whenNotMatched: "fail"
    }}
]);
```

If using `$function` spooks you, you can use a somewhat more obtuse approach with `$reduce` as a stateful for loop substitute.  To better understand what is happening, block comment with `/* */` the stages below `$group` and one by one uncomment each successive stage to see how that operator is affecting the pipeline.

```js
db.foo.aggregate([
    // Get everything in descending order...                                                     
    {$sort: {'points':-1}}

    // ... and turn it into a big array:                                              
    ,{$group: {_id:null, X:{$push: '$$ROOT'}}}

    // Use $reduce as a for loop with state.                                          
    ,{$addFields: {X: {$reduce: {
        input: '$X',

        // The value (stateful) part of the loop will contain a                       
        // counter n and the array newX which we will rebuild with                    
        // the incremental rank:                                                      
        initialValue: {
            n:0,
            newX:[]
        },
        in: {$let: {
           vars: {qq:{$add:['$$value.n',1]}}, // n = n + 1                       
           in: {
               n: '$$qq',
               newX: {$concatArrays: [
                        '$$value.newX',
                        // A little weird but this means "take the 
                        // current item in the array ($$this) and 
                        // set $$this.rank = $qq by merging it into the 
                        // item.  This results in a new object but 
                        // $concatArrays needs an array so wrap it 
                        // with [ ]":
                        [ {$mergeObjects: ['$$this',{rank:'$$qq'}]} ]
                      ]}
                    }
            }}
        }}
    }}

    ,{$unwind: '$X.newX'}
    ,{$replaceRoot: {newRoot: '$X.newX'}}

    ,{$merge: {
        into: "foo",
        on: [ "_id" ],
        whenMatched: "merge",
        whenNotMatched: "fail"
    }}
]);
```